# Neovim - using patched nerdfont but icon not working

Tags: neovim

I am using neovim 0.9. I liked JetBrains Mono font so I downloaded the nerd font patched JetBrains font and installed on my Linux Mint 21.1. All is well except when there is an error, neovim displays this weird icon if the linter/checker gets an error.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Update 6/13/2023.

I think I am missing an icon set.  Do you know where I can get these icons?

[image]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display icons linter/checker/LSP messages, you could configure Neovim diagnostics.

- [Neovim diagnostics documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/diagnostic.html)
- [lsp-config plugin UI Customization](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/UI-Customization)

My Neovim Lua configuration for diagnostic with icons for Error, Warn, Hint, Info:

```lua
-- Configuration for diagnostics
local signs = {
  { name = 'DiagnosticSignError', text = '' },
  { name = 'DiagnosticSignWarn', text = '' },
  { name = 'DiagnosticSignHint', text = '' },
  { name = 'DiagnosticSignInfo', text = '' },
}

for _, sign in ipairs(signs) do
  vim.fn.sign_define(sign.name, { texthl = sign.name, text = sign.text, numhl = '' })
end

local config = {
  signs = {
    active = signs, -- show signs
  },
  update_in_insert = false,
  underline = true,
  severity_sort = true,
  float = {
    focusable = true,
    style = 'minimal',
    border = 'single',
    source = 'always',
    header = 'Diagnostic',
    prefix = '',
  },
}

vim.diagnostic.config(config)
```

Comment: i copied your lua code.  i've a quick question.  The icon for 'DiagosticsSignHint" is coming up as 'F834'.  This is the same issue with my neovim.  I think I need to install some icon sets.  What is the icon for 'DiagnosticsSignHint'?

Comment: If you have some issues with icons for LSP diagnostics, you could install Noto Emoji font (https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji) or try to copy/paste icons from https://github.com/nvim-lua/lsp-status.nvim/blob/master/lua/lsp-status.lua

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.  I've installed the font manager app.  it shows all icons attached to the nerd font.  I've picked few and copy / paste into the file.  It's working now.